# Data is not stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm developing an eCommerce website. In which, I have added code for shopping cart. But, it can't store the data in the cart table in mysql.

Here is the code:

```php
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "puri_database";

  $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

  //Function for getting user ip address
  function getRealIpAddr() {
       if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
       //check ip from share internet
       {
       $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
       }
       elseif (!empty ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
       $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
       }
       else{
       $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       }
       return $ip;
  }

   function cart() {

           global $db;
           if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])){             

           $p_id = $_GET['add_cart'];
           $ip_add = getRealIpAddr();

           $check_pro = "select * from cart where p_id='$p_id' AND ip_add='$ip_add'";
           $run_check = mysqli_query($db,$check_pro);

           if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0){
            echo "Product is Already Exist";
           }
           else{
            $q = "insert into cart (p_id,ip_add) values ('$p_id','$ip_add')";
            $run_q = mysqli_query($db,$q);
            echo "Product is added to cart successfully";
           }

           }
   }
```

Can you help me guys to resolve this problem?

Comment: please initialize the `$db` variable with a mysql connection i assume this is the cause..

Comment: Your code is suseptable to SQL Injection. Please use prepared queries.

Comment: first check if the program execution came to the line of the insert sql, if so then what is the mysql error you are getting ?

Comment: `$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`

Comment: What is the result of the $check_pro query? Are you sure the first part of the if isn't being executed? You might try echo "Exists" just to see.

Comment: @Kunal Awasthi I have already initialize the $db variable and there is no mistake.

Comment: @ Sloan Thrasher ..When I use echo it shows whatever I write on this...And also the else part will be executed successfully but data is not stored in my database.

Comment: Guys just wait for a minute i will provide you more code

Comment: Would be useful to have the definition of the cart table.

Comment: What does `var_dump($run_q);` show? Why do you write that it's added successfully without checking if it was really successful?

Comment: @Barmar It shows C:\wamp64\www\puri_jewellers\functions\functions.php:43:boolean false

Comment: That means the insert failed. Use `echo mysqli_error($db);` to see the reason.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Barmar I will check it.

Comment: It tells Incorrect integer value: '::1' for column 'ip_add' at row 1

Comment: It is solved now @Barmar. I found my mistake. Thanks once again.

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong datatype for your `ip_add` column, it should be `VARCHAR`, not `INT`.

Comment: Yes , I have changed now